# data.table conditional aggregation to list column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to aggregate a data from a data.table to create a new column which is a list of previous rows conditionally.

```
dt <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,10,10,10), letter = c('a','a','b','c','a','c','d','d','e'))
```

A prior example had this as a solution.

```
dt[, list(lst=list(letter)), by=id]

   id     lst
   1 a,a,b,c
   2     a,c
   10   d,d,e
```

I have an additional requirement that it only aggregates if the id difference is less than 2 from the previous value

The solution would close to this :

```
data.table(groupid=c(1,2),lst=c(list(c('a,a,b,c,a,c')),list(c('d,d,e'))))

groupid         lst
1:              a,a,b,c,a,c
2:              d,d,e
```

Comment: please show your desired output; "if the id difference is one"? difference between what? Make sure your example data includes both scenarios.. i.e. where you do want aggregation, and where you do not want aggregation

Comment: I still think the edited post is difficult to understand.. Might you expand you example to show what a variety of differences in the id value, and provide an example critical value, and the desired output?

Comment: What about 2 and 3? the difference is also 1

Answer (score 1):

```r
dt[, .(lst = list(letter)), by = .(groupid = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(id) > 1)))]
#    groupid         lst
#      <int>      <list>
# 1:       1 a,a,b,c,a,c
# 2:       2       d,d,e
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually had a problem where I only aggregate rows if the change is smaller than a crit value... lets say 10. Its more of a rolling problem i.e. in the first group can only contain  a,a,b,c,a,c and the second group can only contain  d,d,e

Comment: You talk about the difference of `id`, yet in your sample data the difference is always 1, yet you somehow otherwise find some way to differentiate them. (That's a lot of "different" there.) Now you mention "change" and a crit value, and I don't know how to apply that to your original data. I suggest it would help to update your data to be more representative, and perhaps incorporate whatever crit value you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry about that youre completely right. I messed it up. Its basically group into an appended list iff the next row value is less than a certain value.

Comment: The method doesn't change much. See my edit.

Comment: A rolling problem, then I am happy to look into it. Unfortunately Q is far from well formed.